# Double click on Bootstrap table row filled with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm using Bootstrap in my website and I'm filling my table from a JSON file. How could I get all the data of a selected row?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from choisir where Etudiant_Matricule='".$idEquipe."' order by ordre asc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray3[] = $row;
}
$json_data = json_encode($emparray3);
file_put_contents('tables/fichedevoeux.json', $json_data); ?>

<table data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/fichedevoeux.json" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
<thead>
    <tr>            
        <th data-field="Code" data-sortable="true">Code</th>
        <th data-field="Titre" data-sortable="true">Titre</th>
        <th data-field="Specialite" data-sortable="true">Spécialité</th>
        <th data-field="Technologie" data-sortable="true">Technologie</th>
        <th data-field="Outil" data-sortable="true">Outils</th>
        <th data-field="Promotion_ID" data-sortable="true">Promotions_ID</th>
        <th data-field="Validation" data-sortable="true">Validation</th>                                 
    </tr>
</thead>
</table
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('tr').on('dblclick', function() {
    alert('row clicked');
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a table with some example data already filled so we know the final structure of the table?

Comment: https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/180053Sanstitre.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, thank you.

```
var $result = $('#eventsResult');        
$('#eventsTable')
.on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
   $result.text('Event: dbl-click-row.bs.table');
   console.log(row);
   console.log($element);
});
```

'eventsTable' is the ID of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` in the event handler to get the clicked element and go from there.

E.g. traverse table headers

```
$('tr').on('dblclick', function() {
    $(this).find("th").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-field"));
    });
});
```

Comment: It works, now how can i know which row i'm in it ! because i have no IDs for the <tr> tags. For exemple i want to save all the data of the selected row in a table.

Comment: $(this) is the element on which the event listener fired. So the tr element which has been double clicked. No need to define id's.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I doubt you're going to want to double click the table header, so you'll likely want:

```
$('tbody tr').on('dblclick', function() {
    // what do you need here?
    var fullHtml = $(this).html();
    // want a data tag?
    var dataTag = $(this).data("whatevertag");
});
```

That's about as much as we can answer without any extra information.